# Why alert box does not show updated value?

Tags: javascript

I wrote  very small code for java script.IN this value of message box are  changed  but it shows old value(14+32) instead of updated value(14+32+10).

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
var no=(14+32);
alert(no);
no =(14+32+10);
 </script>
```

Can any one say actual reason behind this?

Comment: Because this is how it is. The `alert` shows the value which is passed to it, nothing else. *edit*: As mentioned, `alert` actually blocks the execution, but still, even if it wasn't blocking, you would not see a change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the order ef execution of these statements is sequential and synchronous, so the `alert` print the current value of `no` at the time of its execution

or in other words: when you change again the value of `no` the `alert` statement has been already executed

Comment: IN java script every thing goes into sequential and synchronous manner?

Comment: Not all: for example timeouts, intervals, ajax calls, web sockets, events... are all asynchronous. JS is by design really asynchronous

Answer (score 1):

`Alert` is synchrounous function (like most of them in JS) so `alert()` pop up before you change `var no`.

Answer (score 0):

because the code is executed downward!

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     var no=(14+32);
     alert(no);
     no =(14+32+10);
     alert(no);
  </script>
```

Now you can see the differences!